# Find curve using midpoint theorem

Tags: analysis, curves

> Determine a curve such that, at every point, the tangent exists and is
> not horizontal. The segment of this tangent between the axis has as
> middle point, the contact point of the curve, and the curve touches
> the points $$(2,4), (-2,4)$$

I'm having trouble with this problem. I have tried to use the midpoint theorem, but I don't see it.

Comment: Can you please provide your work, or attemps?

Answer (score 0):

Tangent $AB$ has equation
$$Y-y=y'(X-x)$$
we have axis intersection points $A\left(\frac{xy'-y}{y'},0\right)$ and $B\left(0,y-xy'\right)$

so the midpoint is
$$P\left(\frac{xy'-y}{2y'},\frac{y-xy'}{2}\right)$$
as $P$ is on the curve we must have
$$\begin{cases}
x=\frac{xy'-y}{2y'}\to y+xy'=0\\
y=\frac{y-xy'}{2}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Consider the second equation, which is equivalent to the first
$$2y=y-xy'\to \frac{y'}{y}=-\frac{1}{x}\to \log y =-\log x+C\to y=\frac{k}{x}$$
as the curve must pass through $(2,4)$ we have $k=8$ so the solution is
$$y=\frac{8}{x}$$
[image]